# Are turnout figures available at the German consulate level for the 2017 Turkish Referendum?

Tags: turkey, germany, data-sources, voter-turnout, turkish-referendum-2017

Among the approximately 3.5 million people with Turkish background living in Germany, about 1.43 million were eligible to cast a vote in the 2017 referendum on the presidential system. Among these, voter turnout was about 50%. Votes were cast in consulates or the embassy.

Overall, *evet* (yes) won the German-Turkish vote with 63%, with marked local differences.  According to the [Rheinische Post](http://www.rp-online.de/politik/ausland/tuerkei-referendum-so-haben-die-tuerken-in-deutschland-gewaehlt-aid-1.6759554), in Berlin, *evet* and *hyir* (no!) were even (50-50), while *evet* had a far bigger lead in Essen (75%) or Düsseldorf (70%).

My question is if this discrepancy between different cities in preferences was accompanied by differences in voter turnout. **Is there a breakdown of voter turnout by consulate?**

Comment: Having read a bit more, the spread is actually not that surprising, the AKP has a strong base in the Ruhrgebiet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is available directly from the Turkish Supreme Electoral Council [here](http://www.ysk.gov.tr/doc/dosyalar/docs/2017Referandum/2017HO-TemsilciliklerdeOyKullanma.pdf).

The data for German consulates in particular have been analysed further in *[Germany's Turkish Voters - What Do We Know?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325069450_Germany%27s_Turkish_Voters_-_What_Do_We_Know)* by Thomas Krumm from the Turkish-German University, in which he provides this chart:

[image]

He also calculates the Spearman's rank correlation coefficient between turnout & 'Yes' vote at the consulate level, finding a positive correlation (0.654, sig. 0.015). This supports your hypothesis that the discrepancies in 'Yes' vote between consulates were accompanied with differences in turnout; generally speaking, the higher the percentage turnout, the higher the percentage of 'Yes' votes.